# Swapping between DirectX11 Vertex and Pixel Shaders

Tags: c++, render, draw, directx-11

so I have been following a tutorial in the Frank Luna book "3D Games programming with DirectX11" and Have been working on a Sky-box. This sky-box is rendering correctly apart from a small tweak needed to the texture. I have created a separate vertex and pixel shader for the Sky Box as it doesn't need so much work in the .fx file. When I draw my object they all draw but when I use the normal vertex and pixel shader which works normally my objects appear black (I think they are not able to get the colour from their shader).

```
_pImmediateContext->RSSetState(_solidFrame);
_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(_pSkyVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(3, 1, &_pTextureSkyMap);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &_pTextureRV);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(1, 1, &_pSpecTextureRV);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(2, 1, &_pNormTextureRV);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &_pSamplerLinear);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(_pSkyPixelShader, nullptr, 0);

//Imported Sky
world = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_sky.GetWorld());
cb.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose(world);
_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(_pConstantBuffer, 0, nullptr, &cb, 0, 0); //Copies the constant buffer to the shaders.
//Draw the Pitch
_sky.Draw(_pd3dDevice, _pImmediateContext);

_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &_pConstantBuffer);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &_pConstantBuffer);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &_pTextureMetalRV);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(1, 1, &_pSpecTextureRV);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(2, 1, &_pNormTextureRV);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &_pSamplerLinear);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(_pPixelShader, nullptr, 0);

//Floor
// Render opaque objects //
// Set vertex buffer for the Floor
_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &_pVertexBufferFloor, &stride, &offset);
// Set index buffer
_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(_pIndexBufferFloor, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);
world = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_worldFloor);
cb.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose(world);
_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(_pConstantBuffer, 0, nullptr, &cb, 0, 0); //Copies the constant buffer to the shaders.
_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(96, 0, 0);

//Imported Pitch
world = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_pitch.GetWorld());
cb.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose(world);
_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(_pConstantBuffer, 0, nullptr, &cb, 0, 0); //Copies the constant buffer to the shaders.
//Draw the Pitch
_pitch.Draw(_pd3dDevice, _pImmediateContext);

_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &_pTextureMetalRV);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(1, 1, &_pSpecTextureMetalRV);
_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(2, 1, &_pNormTextureMetalRV);
```

Am i missing out a line of code to clear something between changing the shaders and not using the wrong data??

Comment: http://imgur.com/tmfMrya if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a problem with a small edit to the .fx file that I hadn't noticed. Is now fixed by reverting that file back.